# Is it possible to reduce the NER model for training on an existing SpaCy model?

Tags: spacy

I have an already existing spaCy model which I want to refine with additional training data at runtime.

For example a training dataSet in my training model looks like this:

```
text="Anna lives in Munich and works at BMW"
entity: name=Anna 
entity: city=Munich
entity: company=BMW
```

In my implementation I take the ner from the existing model before I start my new training with:

```py
    nlp = spacy.load(modelPath)
    ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')
```

and than I train my existing model with my new TrainingData:

```py
    # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch which is much faster than 
        batches = minibatch(trainingData, size=compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001))
        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(
                texts,  # batch of texts
                annotations,  # batch of annotations
                #drop=0.5,  # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
                losses=losses,
            )
```

Now I have the following question:
My existing ner model contains already the three entities with the labels

```
city, name, company
```

But my new training dataSet has only the entities 'city' and 'name' (not the entity 'company'). Like

```
text="Bob lives in London"
entity: name=Bob 
entity: city=London
```

Because only 'city' and 'name' are part of my sentence.

Now I had the impression that my model quality downgrades if I retrain my model with training datasets containing less entities that in the current model knows.

Would it be clever to (re)set the ner in my model with only the entity labels contained in my current training dataset before I start the training?

Something like this:

```py
    ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
    nlp.add_pipe(ner)
    ner.add_label('city')
    ner.add_label('name')
```

Or does this not make sense?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I had the impression that my model quality downgrades if I retrain my model with training datasets containing less entities that in the current model knows.

Yes. This is called `catastrophic forgetting`.

> Would it be clever to (re)set the ner in my model with only the entity labels contained in my current training dataset before I start the training?

In my opinion, yes. If your current training data doesn't not have company names in it, the model will be become biased as you keep training it, and say in the future you decide to use the same model to detect company names, it will detect city or names as company because it has forgotten what company names are.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But did you recommend to build a new NER for each training data set as long as some of my training data sets contain a company name and some does not. Even on the spacy homepage there is a similar example with a mixed training data set containing two different sentences/entities: https://spacy.io/usage/examples#training-ner  I understand this example that new entity labels are only added if not yet part of the existing model?

Comment: @Ralph: Unfortunately, I do not fully comprehend your question. Can you please break it down for me a little more? 

Comment: Your hint to the 'catastrophic forgetting' was good.
But I figured out, that my model quality is not downgraded when I add later trainingdata with less entities. It was a different issue leading me to the wrong direction. 
Should we delete the last comments? Or the complete question? I think the question and your answer are not so bad at all.

Comment: It's best to leave it. Someone else might benefit from it.